# Eslint error: Missing parentheses around multilines JSX react/jsx-wrap-multilines

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx, eslint

I am using Material UI checkbox in my project. I used it the same way it's used in Material UI example: https://material-ui.com/components/checkboxes/
but eslint shows me this error:

**error  Missing parentheses around multilines JSX  react/jsx-wrap-multilines**

```
<FormControlLabel
  control={
    <Checkbox
      checked={data.default}
      value="default"
      onChange={(e) => {
        return setData({ ...data, default: e.target.checked });
      }}
    />
  }
  label="Make default"
/>
```

error is on the line 2 (control={....)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please, see the examples on the [jsx-wrap-multilines rule page](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-wrap-multilines.md):

You can either disable that rule, or wrap any multiline React element into parentheses:

```
<FormControlLabel
  control={( // starting paren here
    <Checkbox
      checked={data.default}
      value="default"
      onChange={(e) => {
        return setData({ ...data, default: e.target.checked });
      }}
    />
  )} // ending paren here
  label="Make default"
/>
```